# Ошибка вызова C++ функции из qml

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

У меня есть два класса, один класс является образом псевдоконтактной книжкой, а второй реализует визуализация данных в qml. И я хочу вызывать некоторые функции с C++, например для динамического отображения результат поиска,функция для загрузки определенного количества данных. Но проблема с которой я столкнулся это, что в вызове `view.model.setList(viewer.getChuck(index, size))`, а так же `search.model.setList(listContact.getSearchResult(text.toString()))`, в файлах ListItemContact.qml, SearchTab.qml возникают следующие ошибки:

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'getChuck' of undefined;

> Error: Unknown method return type:`QList<UserData>`.

Подскажите как исправить данную проблема. Весь нужный код представлен внизу.

contactlistprovider.h

```
class ContactListProvider: public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
 public:
   enum UserDataRoles
  {
    id = Qt::UserRole + 1,
    userName,
    picturePath,
    isFavorite
};
private:
  std::string filePath;
  UserData parse(std::string data);
  QList<UserData> userDataList;
public:
  explicit ContactListProvider(QObject *parent = nullptr, const std::string filePath = "");
  Q_INVOKABLE  void call(int id);
  Q_INVOKABLE  QList<UserData> getChuck(std::size_t index, std::size_t size);
  Q_INVOKABLE  QString getAvailableLetters();
  Q_INVOKABLE  QList<UserData> getSearchResult(std::string inputData);
  Q_INVOKABLE  void save(int id, QString userName, QString picturePath, bool isFavorite);
  Q_INVOKABLE  void remove(int id);
signals:
};
```

contactlistprovider.cpp

```
QList<UserData> ContactListProvider::getSearchResult(std::string inputData)
{
  std::string searchData;
  QList<UserData> userData = getChuck(0, 100);

  for(auto it = this->userDataList.begin(); it != userDataList.end(); ++it)
  {
     searchData = (*it).userName.toUtf8().constData();
     transform(searchData.begin(), searchData.end(), searchData.begin(), ::tolower);

    if(searchData.find(inputData) != std::string::npos)
    {
        userData.push_back((*it));
    }
 }

  return userData;
}

 QList<UserData> ContactListProvider::getChuck(std::size_t index,   std::size_t size)
 {
  QList<UserData> result;
  std::vector<std::string> dataBuf;
  std::ifstream readFile(filePath);
  std::string buf;
  int i = 0;

  while(getline(readFile, buf))
  {
     if(i >= index && i < size)
     {
        dataBuf.push_back(buf);
     }

     ++i;
  }

  readFile.close();

  for(std::string &value:dataBuf)
 {
    result.push_back(parse(value));
 }

  return result;
}
```

viewer.h

```
class Viewer: public QAbstractListModel
{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_ENUMS(UserDataRoles)

public:
  enum UserDataRoles
  {
    id = Qt::UserRole + 1,
    userName,
    picturePath,
    isFavorite
  };

private:
   QList<UserData> viewer;
public:
 Viewer(const QList<UserData> & viewer);
 Q_INVOKABLE void setList(const QList<UserData> & viewer);
 QHash<int,QByteArray> roleNames() const override;
 int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent) const;
 QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const;
};
```

viewer.cpp

```
void Viewer::setList(const QList<UserData> & viewer)
{
  this->viewer = viewer;
}
```

ListItemContact.qml

```
ListView
{
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: view.model
        visible: view.viewType
        snapMode: ListView.snapMode
        clip: true
  /*some code*/
  
  onAtYEndChanged:
     if(gridView.atYEnd)
     {
         size += 9
         view.model.setList(viewer.getChuck(index, size))
     }
  }
```

SearchTab.qml

```
  Rectangle
  {
     id: search
    color: "#858585"
    border.color: "black"
    border.width: 1
    width: parent.width / 3
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    anchors.leftMargin: 30
    anchors.topMargin: 10
    anchors.bottomMargin: 10
    property var model;
    property var listContact;
    property var view;

    TextEdit
    {
       anchors.fill: parent
       width: parent.width
       text: "Search"
       onTextChanged:
       {
          if (text.toString() === "")
          {
            search.model = view
          }

          else
          {
          search.model.setList(listContact.getSearchResult(text.toString()))
        }
      }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html#exposing-properties

У Вас обращение к атрибуту `.model.` которое не будет работать напрямую. чтоб передать model в qml нужно использовать Q_PROPERTY или передавать из функции